# DAX: Return only selected value when multiple values are returned upon selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset in Power BI that is set up with a hierarchical, many-to-many relationship where an item in the item dimension can be assigned to multiple products in the product dimension, and vice versa.

Below are my dimension tables:

Items:

[image]

Products:

[image]

Urls:

[image]

Bridge:

[image]

My relationship model:

[image]

I want to display a url value related to a single item or product upon selection. I created two many-to-one relationships with the bridge table, however, when I select a single item in a card, multiple products are also selected and vice versa. This causes the url for the first product related to the item to be displayed rather than the item url. See below:

[image]

The url is showing as "aa" which is actually the url for Product 1, not Item 1, which is selected in the bottom card. How can I display the url for the single item or product I've selected? The relationship between items and products has to be bidirectional for the functionality between the cards to work.

Comment: It's always good when you provide your measure code. This creates less gueses. Did you try this: `SELECTEDVALUE(Items[URLID])` ?

Comment: I did, but that only shows the item urls. The user needs to be able to select either items or products in their respective cards, but just show the url of the one selected.

Comment: I added the measure as answer, so check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= IF(
     ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE(DIMITEM[URLID]))
     ,SELECTEDVALUE(DIMPRODUCT[URLID])
     ,SELECTEDVALUE(DIMITEM[URLID])
  )
```